# Steps to decrease delay for parsing desired date time format in Android RecyclerView?

Tags: android, datetime, parsing, android-recyclerview, datetime-format

I am trying to show around `20-100` items in a `RecyclerView`, where I am showing time for every item, and in order to show the time first I need to `Parse` and `Format` the time in a given format which is taking around `900ms` for around `50` items.

I can have two technique to decrease this time delay.

1. I can store the desired timestamp so that only for first time it will take around `900` ms to compute the desired format, but after that every time I will directly show this already computed timestamp.
2. Without storing anything I can directly call formatted `function` inside my `onBindViewHolder` and every time I can compute it which takes around `30-40` ms for the first item and then delay decreases for the next items.

Here in the second approach `900 ms` will get saved but I will need to compute it again and again.

Can anyone please tell me when you approach such kind of problems where the delay is significant which approach do you use? Also, if there is any other approach which you guys use then please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you do more profiling to determine exactly how your time is being spent. My guess is that your 900ms for 50 items may be 900ms for the very first item and <1ms for the rest. Loading time zone information is a one-time cost when using many date/time parsing and formatting options.

Comment: @CommonsWare For the first item it is taking around `30 ms` and for second around `25-30 ms`, but for last items it is taking around `6 ms`.

Comment: That sounds like the results of just-in-time compilation, but I am surprised that it is still that slow per call. You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve] showing how you are doing this work. A typical approach is to combine the two techniques that you outline: perform data conversions like date parsing/formatting lazily and cache the results (e.g., in a viewmodel).